# Error element is no longer attached to the dom ( winappdriver, appium-desktop)

Tags: c#, appium-desktop, winappdriver

I have an automation suite that runs on a desktop application developed on C#, and our Windows apps using Appium Windowsdriver.
Below the code executed after every test case to return to start page.

This is the automation suite :
Launch application

1. Execute first Test test successed
2. Return to StartPage test successed
3. Execute second Test test successed
4. Return to StartPage test not successed "error message "element is no longer attached to the dom"
5. Execute third Test
6. Return to StartPage
   Close application

At step 4 the excucution is stopped with error that the element "Écran de demarage" in no longer attached to the dom.

can you help me plz on that.*

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why is not working?") must include the desired behaviour, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex

Answer (score 0):

When you return to the start page, in step 4, can you initialize a new object for startpage ?